# Update Countdown Timestamp According to Timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Hi I have a countdown timer in my app and I am looking for a way to take my timestamp date and modify it based on the time zone without formatting it.  The time stamp is GMT and it looks like this:

```
theDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1387929601];
```

Then I have my countdown formatter here:

```
-(void)updateCountdownText
{
        //Update the Countdown Label
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        int units =  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:theDate options:0];
        [dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components day], 'd', [components hour], 'h', [components minute], 'm', [components second], 's']];

    }
```

Since I'm already formatting the timestamp below all i would like to do is take the GMT timestamp number and convert it according to the local time zone.  So I would just like to add the time zone code before the dateWithTimeInterval and then change that number (keeping it a timestamp) according to the time zone.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `NSDateFormatter` and you will get the correct timezone and formatting options for free?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
        //Timestamp convert to NSDate
        double time=[myString doubleValue];//in yourcase mystring=@"1387929601"; mystring is timestamp
        NSTimeInterval interval =time ;
        NSDate *online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a dd-MMM-yyyy"];
        NSLog(@"Timestamp date is: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);

        NSString *mystr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:online];
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDate *now = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mystr];

        value1=([[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]);
        value1=value1/3600;
        float value123=((value1) * 3600);

        NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(value123)]; // for PST
        NSDateComponents *dc = [cal components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit   fromDate:now];
        [cal setTimeZone:tz];

        NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:dc];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a dd-MMM-yyyy"];

        NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

May it will work for you.

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter to get correct time zone of your theDate object.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeZone` has a property `secondsFromGMT`. So you can use `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone].secondsFromGMT;` to obtain the difference, add it to your time interval and instantiate the date.

Answer (score 0):

Format the NSDate to adjust for time zone:

```
NSTimeZone *tz = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(-8 * 3600)];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
NSString* s = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```